# Open an android xml file with right editor automatically

Tags: eclipse

Some days ago, The Eclipse doesn't open Android `.xml` file with right editor such as Layout Editor, Drawable Editor,... It always open with resource editor.

So, How can fix this issue?
I am using Eclipse Indigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Window -> Preferences`, and check `General -> Editors -> File Associations` and `General -> Content Types`.

Or right click on such a file in one of the Explorer views, and select `Open With -> ...`

Comment: But what should I do to make eclipse open xml file with right editor automatically?

Comment: This should be possible in `General -> Editors -> File Associations`